# CI HT12E enable control to reduce power consumption

Tags: transistors, capacitor, rf, integrated-circuit, 433mhz

So, following this [datasheet](https://www.eleinmec.com/datasheets/ds_holtek_ht12e.pdf) (check out Application Circuit 4), I managed to transmit a signal and receive it on the other end. The thing now is: the whole circuit is drawing 2 mA, and that is because it is always active, meaning that, the TE pin is always grounded. My efforts now are to only enable TE when the button is pressed, so I changed the circuit a little bit, so that the switch would ground both TE and the AD pin. After tweaking with it a little bit, I figured out that that the TE pin should be grounded a little longer then the AD pin, and I would like to know how to do that.

Comment: "I figured out that that the TE pin should be grounded a little longer then the AD pin"_ - what happens if it isn't? Page 8 of the datasheet shows a typical circuit that uses diodes to turn on the transmitter when any button is pressed.

Comment: If the TE pin is not grounded before AD, the receiver still indicates it is receiving the signal. I am using the H12TD as a decoder, and followed this datasheet: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/57850.pdf, Maybe I am missing something on the receiving side?

Comment: _"If the TE pin is not grounded before AD, the receiver still indicates it is receiving the signal."- So you're saying that VT stays high after the transmitter is turned off?

Comment: I hooked up the diode as you pointed out in the datasheet and measured the voltage on VT. Seems normal on this side, not sure why the LED on the receiver is not always turning off when I release the button... Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the LED connected to? If it's one of the data outputs then this is normal because they are latching.

Comment: The LED is connected to the HT12D output with a sereis resistor. So that si normal? What is latching? Also, when I touch the HT12E's pin, it seems to 'clear' the HT12D's LED

Comment: Latching means the data pin holds its state after the transmission ends. Typically used to turn a circuit on or off depending on which button is pressed.

Comment: So, in order to turn the LED on and then off, I would need to send 2 different pulses? One where the AD pin is on GND, and one where it is open? How would I do that?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Even if it is latching, it should flip the LED every time I send a signal, right? But it does not. It just flips some times, but whenever I touch the pin, it resets. Is there somethign i am missing?

Comment: You are absolutely right. The reason why the LED was turning off is because I was grounding it by touching it :(. The circuit is latching, and that is why it should not change its value. Can you post that answer, so that I can vote it up?

Answer (score 0):

> After tweaking with it a little bit, I figured out that that the TE
>   pin should be grounded a **little longer** then the AD pin...

If the delay is in a few micro seconds or milli Seconds:.

1. Add a series resistor between the switch and the TE Pin.
2. A capacitor between TE pin to ground.
3. This will also increase ON (high to low) time of the signal. If this is not okay, Addng a diode will help to bypass the RC time constant.

Let me know the delay you are looking for and I could propose a circuit.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about where to put that capacitor? I tried the resistor and the diode, but no luck :(

Comment: 500ms should be enought for a delay

Comment: @Pastre 500ms will call for really big capacitor. Are you sure about the timing?. 500 ms delay is not the problem.. I want to be sure that 500ms delay will definitely solve this. You were concerned about 2mA. If it is a battery powered application then we should see about the Energy spent in charging and discharging too.hence..

Comment: The delay can be shorter, but I don't think it will fix it. As discussed in the comments of the question, the receiver circuit is latching, which means I should, instead, send 2 different pulses: one where AD and GND are grounded, followed by one where only AD is grounded. I don't event know how to ask for help now :(